# c++ win32 : adding values to ComboBox

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox

Im sure this question is so easy for all you experts, but I am new to C++ and trying to add a comboBox to a "Option" Dialog in my program, I have done the following, but still can't see any item in Combo box can you please tell me what I am missing here.

in Resourse.h : `#define IDD_TRIGGER_MODE       201`

in Project.rc : `COMBOBOX        IDD_TRIGGER_MODE, 64,22,68,14,WS_TABSTOP | WS_VSCROLL | CBS_DROPDOWN`

any in the .cpp file I have the folliwng codes :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
int wmId, wmEvent;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;

switch (message)
{
case WM_COMMAND:    
    ///Other codes///
        case IDM_OPTIONS:       

    g_hToolbar = CreateDialog(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_OPTION_BOX), hWnd, ToolDlgProc);
    if(g_hToolbar != NULL)
    {
        ShowWindow(g_hToolbar, SW_SHOW);
    }        
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    break;
///Other codes///
}
```

the ToolDlgProc function :

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK ToolDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
 HWND fgModes;

switch (message)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
     fgModes = ::GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDD_TRIGGER_MODE);
  fgModes = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDD_TRIGGER_MODE); 
     if(fgModes!=NULL){
     if(SendMessage(fgModes,CB_ADDSTRING,0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM (_T("FreeRun")))==NULL){            
        return (INT_PTR)FALSE ;          
     }                  
    return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
     }

case WM_COMMAND:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
    {
        EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    }
    break;
}
return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

I appricate it for any idea to solve this problem, Thank you

Comment: Concerning this reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>((LPCTSTR)modes[Count])); why are you passing modes[Count]? It doesn't look right. Just a thought.

Comment: because I want to pass the values from the array. what do you suggest?

Comment: Did you verify that `GetDlgItem()` is returning a non-NULL `HWND`? What is the return value of `SendMessage(CB_ADDSTRING)`? If successful, it returns the index of the inserted string. Lastly, you are casting a `char*` to a `LPCTSTR`. If your app is compiled with Unicode enabled, `LPCTSTR` will map to `wchar_t*` instead of `char*`. You cannot cast a `char*` to a `wchar_t*`. You should change your array to hold `TCHAR*` entries instead of `char*` entries.

Comment: Dear Remy, I used the following code:  if(fgModes!=NULL){
   if(SendMessage(fgModes,CB_ADDSTRING,0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(_T("FreeRun")))==NULL){   
   return (INT_PTR)FALSE ;    
   }               
  return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
   } I notice GetDlgItem() is not returning NULL value, but SendMessage() is returning a NULL value, is there any reason for that? do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure that IDD_TRIGGER_MODE is an ID of the combobox resource in your dialog template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thank you so much for your help. but I notice I didnt have problem in my code, simply the size of the ComboBox in .rc file was quite small (because of my lack of experiance in c++ API), so I change it to 42 now I can see my items. here is the edited code :

`COMBOBOX        IDD_TRIGGER_MODE, 64,22,69,42,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|CBS_DROPDOWNLIST`

Comment: This is a big gotcha for using ComboBoxes in Win32 in my opinion. I posted information about it on the Win32 ComboBox example page: `Height requirement on ComboBox  --
The size of the dropdown of a combobox NEEDS to be included in the height parameter of the combobox initially.  Otherwise it will cut off any drop down elements.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298364(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
SendMessage(fgModes,CB_ADDSTRING,0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>("FreeRun"));
```

To:

```
SendMessage(fgModes,CB_ADDSTRING,0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(_T("FreeRun")));
```

Also is there a good reason you are mixing `CreateWindow/Ex` and resources? I am assuming `CreateWindow/Ex` because I see you are using a `WndProc` for the first cpp, not a `DialogProc`.

Comment: hi Mike,thank you for your help, I changes the SendMessage() and I Notice I its returning a NULL value, do you know why? also about CreateWindow/Ex I am new to c++ programming, thats why Im not sure what im doing what do you recommned?

Comment: It should be returning 0 for the first item since it represents the zero-based index of the string in the listbox. Did a string not appear visually yet?